# Expression evaluation in linker script

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors, linker-scripts

In a GNU LD linker script, I have the following code

```
_. = ASSERT((__SEC1_FREE_END - __SEC2_VAR_START)>= 128,"Report error");
```

The above command does not report an error if `__SEC2_VAR_START` is greater than `__SEC1_FREE_END`,
i.e when the subtraction operation evaluates to be a negative number the linker does not report an error and exit as expected.
I scanned through several documentation files but could not find if any typecasting is done while evaluating the expressions in linker scripts.

How can we explain the behaviour exhibited here?

Comment: probably __SEC2_VAR_START is larger than __SEC1_FREE_END which is quite logical according to the names given. Change the order or change the comparition